# Join only some cells from a column - Openrefine

Tags: cell, openrefine

I've a dataset like this:

[image]

I need to join only the last three columns (the authors) and the join function is not helping me. I don't have always 3 authors: they can be 2, it can be 1.
Is there a way to join only the cells which have empty cells in the near column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution a bit simpler is to use `slice()` to select all values on each record except the first one :

```
row.record.cells['Column name'].value.slice(1).join("|")
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Here is the doc of this function : https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-Array-Functions#slicearray-a-number-from-optional-number-to

Answer (score 1):

Well, I used a workaround:

- first I add another column with `row.record.cells.NameColumn.value.join("|")`
- then in the new column I eliminated the book title doing `value.replace(/(^[^\|]+)\|(.+)$/, "$2")`